how to reference a subset of child nodes whose element names are number
Im trying to transform an XML doc where there is an address node that has child elements Address[1-9]
currently, Im using the following xslt to concatenate all the lines into a single output
out:AddressLine
<xsl:value-of select="$nodeOfAddress/*[starts-with(name(), 'in:AddressLine')]/text()[normalize-space()]/normalize-space()" separator=" "/>
</out:AddressLine>
This seems to work great for ALL address lines.  However, I only want to do this for lines 3-6, not all 9 of them.  Is there a way specify that in the for each select?  Im sure I could hack out a way with a few if statements, but was hoping maybe there is a way similar to what I have above.
I was asked for a sample in file.  I looks something like this
<in:AddressNode>
    <in:AddressLine1>Value1</in:AddressLine1>
    <in:AddressLine2>Value1</in:AddressLine2>
    <in:AddressLine3>Value1</in:AddressLine3>
    <in:AddressLine4>Value1</in:AddressLine4>
    <in:AddressLine5>Value1</in:AddressLine5>
    <in:AddressLine6>Value1</in:AddressLine6>
    <in:AddressLine7>Value1</in:AddressLine7>
    <in:AddressLine8>Value1</in:AddressLine8>
    <in:AddressLine9>Value1</in:AddressLine9>
</in:AddressNode>

I just want address3, 4, 5, and 6

Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input and the expected output.

I see only 6 lines not 9. But the bigger problem is which comes first: the condition that the line is not empty, or the position.

Good question. I think it should output values from AddressLine 3, 4, 5, and 6 as long as they are not empty

So put the position predicate before the normalize one.

Thanks everyone...worked like a charm

Maybe:
<xsl:value-of select="$NodeOfAddress/*[starts-with(name(), 'in:AddressLine')][3 le position() and position() le 6]" /> 

Hard to be sure without seeing the input.

You can use the sequence (3, 4, 5, 6) (which I've written below in the equivalent form (3 to 6)) in your predicate to select the AddressLine child elements by position() e.g.:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:out="out"
  xmlns:in="in">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeOfAddressLine" select="in:AddressNode/*"/>
    <out:AddressLine><xsl:value-of 
      select="$nodeOfAddressLine[position()=(3 to 6)]" 
      separator=" "
    /></out:AddressLine>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

That's assuming that your sample input is really representative, and that the only children of AddressNode are the AddressLine elements you want. But if that the AddressNode element does have other children, then you'd need to select only the ones whose names start with AddressLine, e.g.
    <xsl:variable name="nodeOfAddressLine" 
       select="in:AddressNode/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'AddressLine')]"/>

Personally I would probably just explicitly select the various AddressLine elements by name, if there are only 4 different elements, as I think it makes the intent clearer.
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:out="out"
  xmlns:in="in">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <out:AddressLine><xsl:value-of 
      select="in:AddressNode/
         (in:AddressLine3 | in:AddressLine4 | in:AddressLine5 | in:AddressLine6)"
      separator=" "
    /></out:AddressLine>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


If the prefix: in in your xml and/or the positions of your child-elements can vary, I would use this:
<xsl:value-of select="$NodeOfAddress/*[number(substring-after(name(),'AddressLine')) = (3 to 6)]" />   

